# Search for an Word in List 1 and remove words from a List 2 if they match

Tags: python-3.x, file, loops, text-files, word-list

i have two long list with words in a txt. file. In one of them is Lines with sentences. If the words from Second list, is found in the one of the Sentence, i need to remove it.

Titels.txt:

```
Samsung SM-G960F S9
Samsung SM-G950F S8
Iphone A1906 8
Samsung SM-G940F S7
```

Remove.txt("Words" to remove):

```
SM-G960F
SM-G950F
A1906
SM-G940F
A1904
SM-G930F
```

New_Titels.txt(How it's need to look like):

```
Samsung S9
Samsung S8
Iphone 8
Samsung S7
```

I'm tried this code, but seems to output the same data as before.

```py
infile = "C:/Users/user1/Desktop/Titels.txt"
delfile = "C:/Users/user1/Desktop/Remove.txt"
outfile = "C:/Users/user1/Desktop/New_Titels.txt"

fdel = open(delfile)
fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "w+")
for line in fin:
    for word in fdel:
        line = line.replace(word, "")
    fout.write(line)

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Comment: word contains a new line, try `line.replace(work.strip(), '')`

Comment: also will iterate over fdel more than try readlines at once `fdel = open(delfile).readlines()`

Answer (score 0):

The for-loop for `delfile` will be called multiple times and thus you need to read this file multiple times. The problem is that after reading a file the first time, you need to reset it to read it again. To reset it, either use `f.seek(0)` to reposition to the start of the file, or close it and then open it again which will start from the beginning of the file. Alternatively, you can use `with open(filename)` which will automatically close the file each time it's read. In addition, use `word.strip()` to remove newline character from the end of each line

```
for line in fin:
    with open(delfile) as words:
        for word in words:
            line = line.replace(word.strip(), "")
    fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, there are two problems, `word` has a new line on it and the `fdel` file is being iterated twice, try to read words at once

```
foo = open('foo')
bar = open('bar').readlines()

for line in foo:
    for word in bar:
        line = line.replace(word.strip(), '')
    print(line.strip())
```

Also you can open multiple files with `with` and they will be closed
when the block of `with` finishes

```
with open('foo') as fin, open('bar') as bar:
   ...
```

This will avoid forgetting to call close